# Using ES6 with React in existing Web Site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

I have an existing web site. In this site I have a page available at the URL www.example.com/apps/myApp. myApp is hosted within an existing HTML page. This is just a utility app, so I want to use this as an opportunity to learn React.

Is there a way to use ES6 within this page without importing the entire toolchain? In other words, I'd like to just include React, write my code in ES6, and run. I don't want to have to bring in Gulp or Webpack and introduce some pre-compilation step. Is this possible, or do I have to bring in the whole enchilada?

I've been trying to get to a basic place where I can do this as shown in this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/drzClAekaIsXcXDuOAZz?p=preview). Which, includes the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <div id="myApp"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.14.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [babel-standalone](https://github.com/Daniel15/babel-standalone):

```html
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<div id="myApp"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.14.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-preset="react">
  class MyLayoutComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h3>React Loaded!</h3>
          <br />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  ReactDOM.render(<MyLayoutComponent />, document.getElementById('myApp'));
</script>
```

Comment: I tried that approach, but I didn't have any luck. I've updated the question. I also included a Plunk, which can be found here: https://plnkr.co/edit/drzClAekaIsXcXDuOAZz?p=preview. I was expecting it to say "React Loaded", but I haven't seem to be able to get to that point.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. It works as long as the code is inline like you've shown. But, as soon as the code is split into other .js files like in the Plunkr I provided, it doesn't work. I feel like there is some gap that I'm missing, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: @ZachTempleton Try using `<script>` tags, instead of ES6 `import`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can import React library directly to your old project. Just load ReactJS library like any other JS file.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.js"></script>
```

Check out 
[ReactJS Getting Started for documenation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html)

For writing ES6 you also need BabelJS

Update after auther edit first post. Check out this example code on plnkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/cHnZA04t4Kci33howJ0Z?p=preview).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="myApp"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">

      var TestOut = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
              return (
                <h1>Hello world!</h1>
                );
            }
      });

      ReactDOM.render(
        <TestOut />,
        document.getElementById('myApp')
      );
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.14.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I updated the question showing what I'm trying to do. I included a Plunkr. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: I assumed app.js was inferred by the react.js library based on other examples I've seen. Even when I directly reference it in the Plunkr though, it doesn't work.